# Visual Studio C++ : identifier undefined from a library

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

I am working in restructuring a former program which relies heavily on a external library 
ChronoEngine.lib
I created a new project which holds the same additional include directories, linkers etc... than the former one

I have the following piece of code in a header file

```
#ifndef DRAW
#define DRAW
#include "physics/CHsystem.h"

class draw
{
public:
   // Change size
   static void changeSize(int w, int h);

   // World definition
   static void drawSky(double halfSize, double red, double green, double blue);
   static void drawChair() ;
   static void drawCDG() ;
   static void drawPlane();

   // Geometrical definition
   static void drawSphere(ChBody* body);
   static void drawBox(ChBody* body);
};
#endif
```

this is the same header file as in the previous project, but here visual studio does not find the definition of ChBody (which is included in the "physics/CHsystem.h" header file definition - this file includes physics/ChBody.h -)
when i right click on ChBody to find the reference, visual studio finds 5 references (1 is the real definition (from ChBody.h), 4 others are forward references in others files from the library)

how can I tell my program to find the real definition of the class ? Apparently, it is not a problem of being linked to the library, but more like a referencing problem

my main.cpp is only printing something to the screen for the time being, and draw.cpp is empty (i haven't defined the function i am declaring in draw.h for the time being)

Thanks
Best
Vincent

Comment: What does the declaration of ChBody actually look like? Is it in a namespace?

Comment: also, posting the actual error text might help.

Comment: Here you can simple "comment" #include "physics/CHsystem.h"
and in it place forward-declare :  class ChBody; . Also, check if the file is in the correct location and DRAW is not used...and....

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot
Actually that was a fairly easy problem to solve

The problem was coming from the fact that the other classes (such as ChBody) were defined in a namespace
therefore, adding

```
using namespace <the name of the namespace>;
```

before the definition of the class and after the #include solves this kind of issues.

Thanks
Best
Vincent